# Decrypt MySQL fields created using Java AESBouncyCastle

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, aes

I have method to encrypt and decrypt in Java. How can I reproduce using MySQL command?

```
public static String encrypt(String plainString) throws Exception{
    byte[] encr  = AESBouncyCastle.encrypt(plainString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "secretKey");
    String encryptedString= Hex.encodeHexString(encr);
    return encryptedString;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedString) throws Exception{      
    byte[] retr = AESBouncyCastle.decrypt(Hex.decodeHex(encryptedString.toCharArray()), "secretKey");
    String decryptedString = new String(retr, "UTF-8");
    return decryptedString .trim();
}
```

Any idea where I'm doing wrong? Ultimately I want to see whether I can use AES_DECRYPT function in MySQL to decrypt the string.

### UPDATE

First I need to figure out Mysql equivalent for Java's Hex.decodeHex. We are using Apache's common codec library.

I tried UNHEX in MySQL and did the same in Java, but the results are different.

When I did UNHEX('956cafe431f5bfc0e66ca7d89359d2e9b63060a3ed5793e60c67aacaca43117c')
it returns me something like this **•l¯ä1õ¿Àæl§Ø“YÒé¶0`£íW“ægªÊÊC|** . Whereas Java returns something like this **[B@32267cbc** for
    Hex.decodeHex("956cafe431f5bfc0e66ca7d89359d2e9b63060a3ed5793e60c67aacaca43117c".toCharArray())

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, you can use AES_DECRYPT function in MySQL to decrypt the string.

linke here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html